# UITableViewCell disclosure indicator inheriting UIButton's Appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

When my app launches, I'm setting `[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor someColor]]` in order to modify the appearance of the buttons throughout my app. However, this appears to have given me the unwanted side-effect of also changing the background color of the disclosure indicators in my table views. It seems to only set the un-selected state, so if I press-and-hold on the cell, the background color goes clear.

Setting the background color on the cell's `accessoryView` does not work as I'm not using my own accessory view, just setting the `accessoryType` to use the disclosure indicator.

I've seen some other questions about trying to change the accessory's background to match the cell's background color, which seem to involve using a custom accessory `UIImageView` or setting the background color on the `contentView` instead of the cell. The latter doesn't apply because that's not the issue I'm having, and the former seems like overkill to "un-override" the `UIButton appearance` that I'm setting.

Is there a way to remove the custom `appearance` setting for the disclosure indicators?

**Edit**: not sure if it matters, but I'm using custom `UITableViewCell`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`appearanceWhenContainedIn:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn%3a) to "reset" the appearance when the UIButton is contained in a UITableViewCell

e.g.:

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```